# Issues when submitting to App Store ITMS-90087 ITMS-90635 ITMS-90209 ITMS-90125 ITMS-90080

Tags: ios, swift

I’m running into some issues when submitting my app the the App Store.

I am using Swift 3.0.3 as well as Carthage to handle my frameworks.

When I’m submitting via xcode I get the following errors :

> WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable
>   'Payload/XXXXXX.app/Frameworks/TOCropViewController.framework' is not
>   a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build
>   settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more
>   information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position
>   Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the
>   LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the
>   binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been
>   built with Apple's linker."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at
>   'XXXXXX.app/…/TOCropViewController.fram…/TOCropViewController' does
>   not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the
>   latest Xcode version."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle
>   "XXXXXXX.app/Frameworks/DropDown.framework" isn’t consistent with the
>   Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains
>   armv7(bitcode) and arm64(bitcode), while the nested bundle Mach-O
>   contains X86_64ALL(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a
>   platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build
>   setting."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for
>   XXXXX/Frameworks/SVProgressHUD.framework contains unsupported
>   architectures '[x86_64, i386]’."

Could someone help me with that?

Some Extra info:

I am using the following list of framework:

- github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0
- github "jonkykong/SideMenu" "master"
- github "SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD"
- github "https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController"
- github "evgenyneu/Auk" ~> 7.0
- github "MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell"
- github "AssistoLab/DropDown"

And here are some snapshots of the errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190693/xcode-6-01-archive-validation-error-invalid-segment-alignment

Comment: A number of your compiled frameworks seems to be x86 rather than ARM. You need to check that theses as being compiled correctly with the correct target settin when you archive your app

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. Could you give me more specific instructions on doing that? Thank you!

Comment: I could solve it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues

Comment: I think your problem is as same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86